# Specify limit of x and y in math equation

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

I have the following linear equation

$y = -0.13x + 3$

This calculates a ratio (y) depending on a computer size in gigabytes. The domain in negative is irrelevant ( x > 0) and the minimum ratio(y) is 1.7. How can I modify this function to better integrate those limits?

Comment: The right side of the equation you typed in is the negative of the one you fed to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y=%281.3x%20-%2030%29%20/%20-10)  In that one the denominator was $-10$.  This one looks like what you intended.  Please confirm.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, I was confused, -10 was what I wanted. I edited the post in a simplified version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have $y \gt 1.7$, you must have $x \lt 10$  Given your comment, you can write $$y=\begin {cases} -0.13x+3& 0 \le x \lt 10\\ 1.7& x \ge 10 \end {cases}$$

Comment: Alright, so we have lim x -> 36 f(x) = (1.3x -30) / - 10 ?

Comment: No, we just say $y=(1.3x-30)/10$, or more simply $y=0.13x-3$ for $x \ge \frac {470}{13}$.  We leave the function undefined for $x$ less that this.  You put the minus sign back in the denominator in your last comment.

Comment: Hmm I don't know, there must be a way to write this better. In what I want to explain, the ratio is linear from (0,3) to (10, 1.7) like the function above. However, if x > 10 then I want the function to return 1.7 not undefined. I just dont know how to write this in a coherent mathematical formula